# Filtration of the category of finite spectra

Tags: stable-homotopy-theory

Consider the stable homotopy category $\mathcal{SHC}$, we then can define its full subcategory $\mathcal{SHC}^c$ spanned by finite spectra which coincides with the smallest thick triangulated subcategory of $\mathcal{SHC}$ generated by $\mathbb{S}$.

I was told that $\mathcal{SHC}^c$ admits a filtration given by the following sets

$C_{(0)}= \{ \Sigma^l \mathbb{S} \ : \ l \in \mathbb{Z} \}$
$C_{(n+1)}= \{ Z : \textit{there exists a distinguished triangle} \ X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z \rightarrow \Sigma X \ \textit{with} \ X, Y \in C_{(n)}   \}$

and the category of $p$-local compact spectra $\mathcal{SHC}^c_p$ inherits a similar filtration since it's the $p$-localization of $\mathcal{SHC}^c$.

I tried to prove that $K= \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} C_{(n)}$ coincides with $\mathcal{SHC}^c$: the inclusion $K \subset \mathcal{SHC}^c$ is trivial, for the other I tried to prove that $K$ is a thick triangulated subcategory of $\mathcal{SHC}$  but I cannot show $K$ is thick.

If someone has any idea how to prove the thickness of $K$ he is welcomed but I suspect that the proof needs some machinery of the stable homotopy category and not only basic theory of triangulated categories.

This is a known fact but I could not find a precise reference in the literature: if you can provide one I will consider it a satisfactory answer.

Thanks in advance for any help.